# DataFormat.Error Power BI Desktop

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, powerbi, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Power BI for analyzing Azure Search statistics. The raw data is gathered on storage account (blob) by Search traffic analytics tool. To import date I've used [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-traffic-analytics/) tutorial. But on applying query changes I'm getting error.
[image]

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: As the error says, there's an invalid escape sequence in the JSON data. You'll need to find it out. Try copy the data and validate it via http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid escape sequence is caused by unescaped backslashes () in the search terms of some queries.

See this question on how to create a power bi query that ignores the errors:
[Azure Search statistics Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878575/azure-search-statistics-power-bi/39967692#39967692)